# Como passar a variável do PHP para Python e obter o output

Tags: php, python

Olá estou tentando rodar um código Python de reconhecimento facial através de uma pagina web eu estou usando esses códigos abaixo:
**PHP**

```
<?php
$directory = "./dados/fotos";
$fotos = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($directory));
foreach($fotos as $knowns){
$r = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("python face.py '/dados/file_2.jpg' '$knowns' 2>&1"));
shell_exec("echo '$r' > tmp2.txt");
}
```

**PYTHON**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import face_recognition
import sys

unknown_loc = sys.argv[1]
knowns = sys.argv[2]

known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("./dados/fotos/{}".format(knowns))
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("{}".format(unknown_loc))

biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([biden_encoding], unknown_encoding)
 if results[0] == True:
 print(knowns)
```

os códigos interagem perfeitamente, quando usado no **terminal** mas quando é usado através do **servidor apache(Xampp)** simplesmente o código python não é executado. estou quebrando a cabeça a 2 dias nisso, então recorri ao stackoverflow, alguma dica do que fazer?

também tentei usar exec():

```
<?php
$directory = "./dados/fotos";
$fotos = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($directory));
foreach($fotos as $knowns){
$r = exec(escapeshellcmd("python face.py '/dados/file_2.jpg' '$knowns' 2>&1"));
exec("echo '$r' > tmp2.txt");
}
```

até mesmo troquei de VPS, mas não entendo o motivo da variável não estar passando para o python, estou tentando usar sys.argv[] para obter os argumentos. também tentei usar o próprio executável
do face_recogtion para resolver meu problema, no código abaixo:

```
<?php
shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("face_recognition dados/fotos file_02.jpg 2>&1")); //assim não precisa usar o foreach
```

mas mesmo assim, o output retorna vazio.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO: 02/07/2022:**
Testei sem utilizar o modulo **SYS** e por algum motivo retornou o output, mas não completo já que sem o sys as variáveis não são replicadas para  o python, segue o código:
**PYTHON**

```
#assim funciona
import requests

print("Funcionou")

#porem utilizando o sys não
import requests
import sys

known = sys.argv[1]
chat = sys.argv[2]

requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/send.php?known={}&chat={}".format(knowns,chat))
//não retorna nenhum valor
print ("Funcionou")
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$r = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("python teste.py 2>&1"));
// caso seja utilizado o python sem o import sys, retorna perfeitamente, mas caso contrario retorna vazio.
print($r);
```

**OBS:** O send.php é um codigo que vai enviar o resultado de volta para a pagina web.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO: 03/07/2022:**

Consegui utilizar o modulo sys, no código, e fazer funcionar tanto no servidor quanto localmente, segue o código:
**PYTHON**

```
import sys
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
print("o argumento foi: {}".format(arg1))
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$arg1 = $_GET["unknown"];
//$chat_id = $_GET["chat"];
$directory = "./dados/fotos";
$fotos = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($directory));
foreach($fotos as $knowns){
$r = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("python teste.py '$knowns' 2>&1"));
print($r);
}
```

mas por algum motivo se eu tento utilizar mais de 1 modulo exemplo import sys e import requests, simplesmente não retorna nada pelo servidor, apenas localmente ;-;

> estou usando o modulo **face_recognition**
> https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition
> **Especificações:** Apache server, php 7.0, ubuntu 18, xampp.
> **Objetivo:** Estou criando uma versão web de um projeto de reconhecimento facial, utilizando como API um código python, citado acima e como motor o PHP 7.0, com citado nas especificações acima.

Comment: Veja as formas de se trabalhar com python em ambiente de produção. Provavelmente é um problema de segurança.

Answer (score -4):

arquivo teste.

```php
<php>
$python =`python inc.py`; #seu arquivo .py
$inc = $python;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($inc);
</>
```

no arquivo inc.py:

```python
inc = 30

print(inc)
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).